# How to remove child Relative layout from ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

In my android `Activity` I am using a `ScrollView` in which I am inserting multiple `RelativeLayout` as child, inside those `RelativeLayout` there is an option to delete that particular `RelativeLayout`. I am using this code to delete `RelativeLayout` from `ScrollView`:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)(view.getParent()).getParent();
            myScollView.removeView(layout);
            myScollView.invalidate();
```

but this code is not working as expected, `RelativeLayout` not removed from the `ScrollView`.

Comment: please provide you layout.xml in a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)(view.getParent()).getParent();
(ViewGroup(layout.getParent())).removeView(layout);
myScollView.invalidate();
```

Comment: @user3804327 : Please mark it as answer so that others can follow...Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To delete the view

```
((ViewManager)entry.getParent()).removeView(entry);
```

or

```
View root = findViewById(R.id.your_root);
root.removeView(yourViewToRemove);
```

You can remove a Child View from a parent by calling removeView(View view),  like this :

```
parent.removeView(child);
```